# How to store scripts using blockfrost?

Tags: plutus, blockfrost, script

Greeting!

I got that Blockfrost has API to get plutus script hash but how to store those scripts hashes?

P.S. if I got script hash, can I build and send transaction using script's hash and Blockfrost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't store scripts using blockfrost.

blockfrost only queries the blockchain and has an endpoint to submit transactions.

when you retrieve a script hash using blockforst you are querying the blockchain

in order to "store" a script on-chain you first have to interact with that script so that the blockchain knows it exists.

[the section 6 of lesson 3 of the plutus-pioneer-program iteration 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABtffZPoUqU&list=PLNEK_Ejlx3x2zxcfoVGARFExzOHwXFCCL&index=6) shows you how to create such a transaction using `cardano-cli`